# How to create the expected list?

Tags: python, list

I have 3 below lists. I want to create an expected_list that has the same shape with list 1 and will contain element in list 2 if the element in list1 has "Review at", otherwise it will be blank ("")

```
list1 = [  "Review abcd"
           "Neu"
           "Review defg"
           "Review hmk"
           "hmd"
           "Review lmi"
           "Review yuj"
           "jmf"
           "Review  Bad"]

list2 = [ "http1"
          "http2"
          "http3"
          "http4"
          "http5"
          "http6"]

expected_list = [ "http1"
                  ""
                  "http2"
                  "http3"
                  ""
                  "http4"
                  "http5"
                  ""
                  "http6"]
```

I tried the following code

```
for idx, item in enumerate(list1): 
    if "Review" in list1[idx]:
        for j in rang(len(list2))
            expected_list.append(list2[j])
    else:
        expected_list.append("")
```

However, in each element that satisfies the condition, it appends all the element in list2. So the shape of the expected list is more than expected. I know creating the 2nd loop is wrong. But how can i fix it ?

Comment: need comma seperated values

Comment: What have you tried to debug why your code is not working?

Answer (score 1):

You simply need something like:

```
for idx, item in enumerate(list1): 
    if "Review" in item: # use *item* here, that's the whole point of enumerate
        expected_list.append(list2[idx])
    else:
        expected_list.append("")
```

Better yet, use `zip`:

```
for item1, item2 in zip(list1, list2):
    if "Review" in item1:
        expected_list.append(item2)
    else:
        expected_list.append("")
```

Answer (score 1):

those lists are one element, you need to seperate values with commas:

[image: need commas]

also, you dont need a lot of stuff there:

```
j = 0
for each in list1: 
    if "Review" in each:
        expected_list.append(list2[j])
    else:
        expected_list.append("")
    j+=1
```

Comment: thank your. In my case, i should put j+=1 in under the line expected_list.append(list2[j]), because if there is no Review in each review, i dont want the index of list2 to increase. Btw thanks for shedding a light for me.